# get user group from facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with facebook graph api in accessing user's group.

If i access directly with this:
https://graph.facebook.com/fb_id/groups?access_token=token

I can access and retrieve group.

However, using php sdk, it returns null. May I know what went wrong?

```
$info = $facebook->api('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$memberfb.'/groups?access_token='.$membertoken);    
$ct = count($info[data]);
```

$ct return 0.

May I know what went wrong here?

Comment: Hi davidlee, can you please tell me something, do u initiliaze the php sdk with the app_id and secret code even if you want to use it for a group?? i'm trying to access a closed group but seems like all the documentation is not taking me to the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you acquired the `user_groups` permission and then use:

```
$info = $facebook->api("/$memberfb/groups?access_token=$membertoken");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the Facebook API, too. And your code is wrong, the right way is:

```
$info = $facebook->api( '/'.$memberfb.'/groups', 'GET', array( 'access_token=' => $membertoken ) );
$ct = count( $info['data'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

The facebook permission required is user_groups

The C# code for getting the groups of a user using FacebookSdk on codeplex is as follows

```
public Dictionary<string,string> GetGroups(string facebookId, string accessToken)
    {            
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        JsonObject resul = facebookClient.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?access_token=" + accessToken) as JsonObject;
        Dictionary<string, string> dicGroups = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (JsonObject item in (((KeyValuePair<string, object>)(resul[0])).Value as JsonArray))
        {
            dicGroups.Add(item["id"].ToString(),item["name"].ToString() );
        }
        return dicGroups;
    }
```